# PHP select from database and compare result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php script dat is suposse to register users into a database. but first I want it to check d user password with a pin code in the data base and the user password and my db pin match den we add the user details  to the database else we echo an error but I dont seem to be getting it. please help me dis d php script

`

```
$connect=mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password")
or die("Bross why na, change the localhost to example site.com without www. ");
$select=mysql_select_db("$db_name")
or die("dagogo change the db");

//collection data from registration form and processing encrypting it
$first_name=($_POST["First_Name"]);//user 1st name
$last_name=($_POST["Last_Name"]);//user last name
$username=($_POST["UserName"]);//user special User name
$phone=($_POST["Phone"]);//user phone number
$email=($_POST["email"]);//user email address
$password=($_POST["password"]);//user password

    //checking the pin with pin in the database

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin_code WHERE pin='$password'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$dbpassword=$row['pin'];

}
if($password==$dbpassword)
{


//inserting the form details into the database.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,username,phone,email,password)VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$username','$phone','$email','$password')")or die ("Registration failed");
}
else
{
echo"dagogo";
}
```

`

and kip on get this error `Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\9ja School Solution\register.php on line 114` wic hapenns to be d last line of d script"?>" please help

Comment: And `line 114` is.......?

Comment: missing closing bracket on # if($numrows!=0){

Comment: THANKS A MILLION d error is off bt it did insert d user dtals this thee cod nw $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin_code WHERE pin='$password'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$dbpassword=$row['pin'];

}
if($password==$dbpassword)
{


//inserting the form details into the database.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,username,phone,email,password)VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$username','$phone','$email','$password')")or die ("Registration failed");
}
}

Comment: @dagogodboss You should consider using MySQLi_ and/or PDO instead MySQL_

Comment: dnt knw pdo or mysqli culd be kind do dis 4 me thanks in advance

Comment: @dagogodboss - Please refrain from using txtspk while at SO. `d` is really not an acceptable substitution for the _word_ `the`. Typing in all capitals is considered shouting,  typing in all lower-case is considered childish. Use proper capitalisation if you want to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 0):

The Error Was You didn't Close the First If Statement No closing Bracket for it (})

Try the following..

```
$connect=mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password")
    or die("Bross why na, change the localhost to example site.com without www. ");
    $select=mysql_select_db("$db_name")
    or die("dagogo change the db");

    //collection data from registration form and processing encrypting it
    $first_name=($_POST["First_Name"]);//user 1st name
    $last_name=($_POST["Last_Name"]);//user last name
    $username=($_POST["UserName"]);//user special User name
    $phone=($_POST["Phone"]);//user phone number
    $email=($_POST["email"]);//user email address
    $password=($_POST["password"]);//user password

    //checking the pin with pin in the database

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pin_code WHERE pin='$password'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {

            $dbpassword=$row['pin'];

        }
        if($password==$dbpassword)
        {


            //inserting the form details into the database.
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,username,phone,email,password)VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$username','$phone','$email','$password')")or die ("Registration failed");
        }
        else
        {
            echo"dagogo";
        }
    }
```